# ¿Se puede operar con decimales en Bash?

Tags: bash, float, coma-flotante

¿Hay alguna forma de operar con decimales en Bash? Hacer operaciones, obviamente. He probado con `let`, pero siempre me arroja un error con la parte decimal.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: La respuesta corta es **no**, pero si tienes instaladas en el sistema herramientas como `bc` sí que puedes hacer uso de ellas desde `bash`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dependiendo de las herramientas que tengas instaladas en el sistema podrás realizar operaciones con decimales, pero [`bash` no las soporta internamente](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> **Arithmetic Evaluation**
>
> The shell allows arithmetic expressions to be evaluated, under certain circumstances. Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow, though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error.

En castellano:

> **Evaluación Aritmética**
>
> La shell permite evaluar expresiones aritméticas bajo ciertas circunstancias. La evaluación es realizada en enteros de ancho fijo (32 o 64 bits) sin comprobación de desbordamiento, aunque la división entre 0 será capturada y tratada como un error.

Se puede saber si el tamaño del entero es de 64 bits probando:

```
$ echo $((1 << 63))
-9223372036854775808
$ echo $((1 << 64))
1
```

Haciendo uso de herramientas instaladas en el sistema:

```
# (En ksh93, zsh y yash, pero no bash)
echo "$((10.5/2))"
awk "BEGIN {print 10.5/2}"         # 5.25
bc <<< "10.5/2"                    # 5
# El resultado se redondea, por lo que si quieres mantener parte decimal:
bc <<< "scale=4; 10.5/2"           # 5.2500
node -pe "10.5/2"                  # 5.25
python -c "print 10.5/2"           # 5.25
php -r 'echo 10.5/2, PHP_EOL;'     # 5.25
```

Para almacenar resultados puedes usar:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Introduzca A: "
read A
echo -n "Introduzca B: "
read B
RESULTADO=$(bc <<< "scale=4; $A * $B")
echo "$A x $B = $RESULTADO"
```

Una ejecución de prueba podría ser:

```
$ bash prueba.sh
Introduzca A: 4.5
Introduzca B: 2.3
4.5 x 2.3 = 10.35
```

Comment: He averiguado también otra manera para utilizar bc, que sería mediante tuberías:

`$ echo "scale=2;10/3" | bc`

Gracias @OscarGarcia

Comment: La redirección `<<< "TEXTO"` es equivalente al `echo "TEXTO" |`, pero con la ventaja de no tener que ejecutar el programa `/bin/echo` con el único propósito de pasar por entrada estándar a otro programa un texto.