# Error al multiplicar con decimales en bash

Tags: bash, terminal

Quiero hacer un script en bash que te pida dos numeros y que muestre el iva de la suma de esos numeros pero al multiplicar el iva me da error.

```
#!/bin/bash


echo PRECIO

read precio

echo CANTIDAD

read cantidad

iva=0.16

total=$(( $precio +$cantidad ) *$iva)

echo $total
```

El error:

PRECIO

5

CANTIDAD

5

```
./ffffffff: command substitution: línea 8: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `*$iva'

./ffffffff: command substitution: línea 8: `( $precio +$ cantidad ) *$iva'
```

Comment: como tal, bash no admite directamente la multiplicacion con decimales. Revisa este otro SO: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194174/se-puede-operar-con-decimales-en-bash. Puedes probar con bc o con let para hacer la operacion.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Se puede operar con decimales en Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194174/se-puede-operar-con-decimales-en-bash)

Answer (score 0):

Encuentro 2 problemas en tu código:

1. Tienes que trabajar con números enteros. Cambia el iva a 16 y luego divide el total entre 100
2. Te falta un par de paréntesis para realizar las operaciones matemáticas

El código me funciona con:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo PRECIO
read precio

echo CANTIDAD
read cantidad

iva=16

total=$(( ( $precio + $cantidad ) * $iva / 100 ))

echo $total
```

Comment: Busque inforamción sobre operaciones con decimales en bash y encontre una solucion para poder harcerlo y es asi:           
                             total=$(echo "scale=1;($precio+$cantidad)* $iva" | bc) Y EL IVA ES 0.16