# Variables con numeros decimales en bash

Tags: bash

He hecho un script que te pide 3 numeros y te saca el mas pequeño de esos tres. Cuando pongo un numero decimal, me da error.

```
#!/bin/bash

read num1 
read num2 
read num3
echo $num1 $num2 $num3

if [ $num1 -lt $num2 ] && [ $num1 -lt $num3 ];then
    echo $num1 es el menor
elif [ $num2 -lt $num1 ] && [ $num2 -lt $num3 ];then
    echo $num2 es el menor
else 
    echo $num3 es el menor
fi
```

El error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bash no opera con decimales, solo con enteros. En [esta respuesta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787/311686) verás la cantidad de formas alternativas que hay para realizar dichos cálculos usando programas que pueden correr en bash e invocándolos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Se puede operar con decimales en Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194174/se-puede-operar-con-decimales-en-bash)

Comment: No mucho la verdad.

Comment: No hagas mucho caso a ese texto que pone `¿Responde esto a tu pregunta?` pues se genera automáticamente cuando alguien marca tu pregunta como duplicada, no lo ha escrito el.  De todos modos, mirando esa respuesta, la veo correcta... ¿porque dices que no responde a tu pregunta?  ¿que respuesta esperabas?  Si bash no opera con decimales, pero se puede trucar el tema con comandos del sistema u otros programas invocados desde bash... ¿que más necesitas saber?